# Using Zend Gdata in Yii framework

Tags: yii, gdata

I am trying to fetch some photos from Picasa by Zend Gdata. This is my code:

```
public function getAlbumFeed($albumName){
    require_once('Zend/Loader.php');
    spl_autoload_unregister(array('YiiBase','autoload'));
    spl_autoload_register(array('Zend_Loader_Autoloader','autoload'));
    spl_autoload_register(array('YiiBase','autoload'));
    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Photos');
    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Http_Client');

    $svc=Zend_Gdata_Photos::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME;
    $client=Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($this->email, $this->password, $svc);
    $gphoto=new Zend_Gdata_Photos($client);

    $query=$gphoto->newAlbumQuery();
    $query->setUser('default');
    $query->setAlbumName($albumName);

    try{
        $feed=$gphoto->getAlbumFeed($query);
    }
    catch(Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e){
        throw new HttpException("Your photos can't find", 404);
    }
    return $feed;
}
```

But when I run this script, my website throw a error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'CExceptionEvent' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework\base\CApplication.php on line 703
```

Could you help me to solve this problem? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the problem is that you are getting an exception thrown (probably that `HttpException` near the end of your code), and Yii wants to construct a `CExceptionEvent` instance so that it can raise the [`CApplication::onException`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#onException-detail) event.

However, Yii's class autoloader has been removed from the autoload stack and as a result PHP cannot find the class.

Try commenting out the code that removes and adds Yii's autoloader and see if it makes a difference:

```
// spl_autoload_unregister(array('YiiBase','autoload'));
spl_autoload_register(array('Zend_Loader_Autoloader','autoload'));
// spl_autoload_register(array('YiiBase','autoload'));
```

You can also call [`spl_autoload_functions`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-functions.php) to check what exactly is going on with your spl_autoload stack -- maybe something has corrupted it:

```
print_r(spl_autoload_functions());
die;  // see what the line above prints

$svc=Zend_Gdata_Photos::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME;
```